# Dúvida sobre Inserir, Consultar, com Classe BD

Tags: java

boa noite.
Estou desenvolvimento um trabalho da faculdade, que pedia que eu criasse uma classe Aluno, implementasse uma interface gráfica, com nome, endereço, opções de curso, lista de escolha e etc, e que eu fizesse botão de sair, consultar e Gravar.

[image: Componente Interface Gráfica]
Porém, a questão pede que eu crie uma classe BDAluno que implemente uma Collection para agrupar um conjunto de objetos Alunos e manipula-los, mas não sei como fazer isso.

Alguem pode me ajudar?

Básicamente, pegar essas informações e jogar para a classe BDAluno:

```
  private void jGravarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        this.txtCidade.setEnabled(true);
        this.jConsultar.setEnabled(false);
        this.jSair.setEnabled(true);
        this.jGravar.setEnabled(false);
        String Nome = txtNome.getText();
        String Endereco = txtEndereco.getText();
        String Cidade = txtCidade.getText();
        String Estado = jEstado.getUIClassID();
        String Sexo ="";
            if(rdMasculino.isSelected()){
                Sexo = "Masculino";
}
            if(rdFeminino.isSelected()){
                Sexo = "Feminino";
}


            BDAluno bda = new BDAluno();

            if( bda.Gravar(Nome, Endereco, Cidade, Estado, Sexo) ) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cadastro Realizado com Sucesso");

        int opcao = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Deseja realizar outro cadastro?:\n1 - Sim\n2 - Não e sair do programa"));

        switch (opcao) {
            case 1:
            initComponents();
            break;
            case 2:
            System.exit(0);
            break;
            default:
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Opção inválida.");
            break;
```

Comment: Forneça um **[mcve]** do que fez até agora para que seja possivel te ajudar.

Comment: Cadê a classe Aluno?